# What is "Correlated Fetch" as talked in Session 214 of WWDC 2012?

Tags: core-data, nspredicate

She was talking about query

```
ANY tag.searchString == "rome" AND label == "red"
```

"is really better done as a correlated fetch" like this:

```
ANY tag IN FETCH(%@, %@, NO) AND label == "red"
```

But I've never heard this thing or seen this syntax before, nor can I find them on web. So what's Correlated Fetch and where can I find documents about it?

Comment: Hi! Any news on this? I also came across that and got very interested in the concept.

Comment: @FábioOliveira Not yet.